Movie in which two gay men smuggle either a worm or parasite in their bodies
My wife is looking for a movie title with the premise being that two gay men are smuggling either a worm or a parasite in their bodies.

In roughly which year did your wife watch this? Also, was the movie set in or near the present day? In the far future?

Could this be Swallowed (2022)?

It follows two friends who, on their final night out, end up smuggling
a wrapped substance, via swallowing, that ends up going awry.
Alice takes the boys in her truck, and explains that the condoms contain larvae with venomous bites that get people high. She takes them to a woodland cabin owned by her boss, Rich, intending to collect the packages from their stools, but when Rich calls to say he is coming to the cabin, she panics and tells Ben to fish them out of Dom with his fingers.





For the record, this film's reviews are appalling. If you have a spare 1hr 36mins and an overwhelming desire to have a worm-themed evening, I'd suggest you go watch Tremors :-)
